# Raspberry Pi blinking LED light errors

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I just got a raspberry pi and have been enjoying it. I am trying to get started with some simple tutorials and am having a problem. The tutorial is this :

http://www.rpiblog.com/2012/09/using-gpio-of-raspberry-pi-to-blink-led.html . But, when I try to run the code I get the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):    File
>   "/home/pi/Desktop/BlinkgLed.py", line 13, in 
>        GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)  RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem.  Try running as root!

The code I am running is

```
 import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
 import time
 # blinking function
 def blink(pin):
         GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.HIGH)
         time.sleep(1)
         GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.LOW)
         time.sleep(1)
         return
 # to use Raspberry Pi board pin numbers
 GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
 # set up GPIO output channel
 GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)
 # blink GPIO17 50 times
 for i in range(0,50):
         blink(11)
 GPIO.cleanup()
```

I tried doing this

```
sudo python
 import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
 import time
 # blinking function
 def blink(pin):
         GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.HIGH)
         time.sleep(1)
         GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.LOW)
         time.sleep(1)
         return
     # to use Raspberry Pi board pin numbers
     GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
     # set up GPIO output channel
     GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)
     # blink GPIO17 50 times
     for i in range(0,50):
             blink(11)
     GPIO.cleanup()
```

And now I get the error

```
 Invalid Syntax
```

I also tried this

```
 sudo idle3
```

and I got this

> Client is not authorized to connect to ServerTraceback (most recent
>   call last):    File "/usr/bin/idle3", line 5, in 
>        main()    File "/usr/lib/python3.2/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 1405, in main
>        root = Tk(className="Idle")    File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1701, in **init**
>        self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)  _tkinter.TclError:
>   couldn't connect to display ":1.0”

Any thoughts on how to solve any of these?

BTW I installed GPIO by this tutorial :

https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/download-and-install/

and was able to make led’s tp turn on and off by code. So I don’t think thats the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your python code is in a file named `test.py` in `/home/user` try to run:

```
$ sudo python /home/user/test.py
```

(adjust accordingly to your environment).

Comment: Now i'm getting the error 'pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo python ~/Desktop/BlinkgLed.py

  File "/home/pi/Desktop/BlinkgLed.py", line 1

    sudo python

              ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax'

Comment: Erase `sudo python` from BlinkgLed.py. This is no python instruction.

Comment: I have this shebang at the top of my .py scripts: #!/user/bin/env python

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a terminal window and type in...

```
sudo idle [Then press return]
```

After that you can go back to the Python window and write the code you need.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The following bash script is about blinking GPIO2 with regard to the user defined time by taking three input variables for amount of hours, minutes and seconds respectively.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /sys/class/gpio
echo 2 > export
cd gpio2
echo out > direction
echo 0 > value
echo -n "enter hour :   "
read hour
echo -n "enter minute :   "
read min
echo 1 > value
for ((i=0;i<$min;i++))
do
sleep 1m
done
for  ((i=0;i<$hour;i++))
do
sleep 1h
done
cd /sys/class/gpio
cd gpio2
echo 0 > value
```